# Store large data in String variable SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a SQL table Which has ID column and in this table around 2,00,000 records are populated.SSIS,I need to store these IDS in to string variable but string cannot accommodate this data.

Comment: Try an object variable.

Comment: Help me understand "I need to store these IDs in to a string variable" To what end?